# Internal server error 500 while ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to call this method:

```
// POST: /Manufacturer/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    Manufacturer manufacturer = unitOfWork.manufacturerRepository.GetByID(id);
    unitOfWork.manufacturerRepository.Delete(manufacturer);
    unitOfWork.Save();
    return Json(new { ok = true, newurl = Url.Action("Index", "Manufacturer") });
}
```

with this ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Manufacturer/Delete/" + $('#Id').val(),
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            headers: {
                'RequestVerificationToken': '@TokenHeaderValue()'
            },
            data: { id: $('#Id').val() },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("error" + data);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.ok)
                {
                    $("#Modal").modal('hide');
                }
                else {
                    $('.modal-body').html(data);
                }
            }
        })
```

I checked in fiddler And I can see the ID is passed correctly. I Put break point at the start of a method but it isn't hit. Call crashes before.
What should I do to find something what is causing this crashes?

data from fiddler:

```
POST http://localhost:1809/Manufacturer/Delete/34 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1809
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 5
Accept: */*
RequestVerificationToken: TQY9NrchHlFT6IBaTv1R4daiwGoRH0yv3gHJwpatGj
Origin: http://localhost:1809
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:1809/Admin/Index
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=r5YwV-v

id=34
```

Comment: What does the HTTP request and response look like?

Comment: Edit and write the HTTP 500 detailed error if you are debugging with debug=true.

Comment: try data: JSON.stringify({
        id: $('#Id').val()
    }),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the id from the `POST` Url.Id in Url is used in a `GET` request.But if you want to use POST Use `Json.stringify()` in the data part of ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Manufacturer/Delete",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        headers: {
            'RequestVerificationToken': '@TokenHeaderValue()'
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: $('#Id').val() }),
        error: function (data) {
            alert("error" + data);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.ok)
            {
                $("#Modal").modal('hide');
            }
            else {
                $('.modal-body').html(data);
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the id from the post URL. This way it passes it to the right method and id can be bound to the posted data "id"

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Manufacturer/Delete/"
            .......
```

When passing the id it should be in a JSON string, here we can use 
**JSON.stringify(value[, replacer [, space]])**.

> data: JSON.stringify({ id: $('#Id').val() })

You can also use XML if u want and parse it to a string by:

> (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml);